# Xcode 3.2.5 fail to create IPA file

Tags: xcode, ipa

I'm trying to create an IPA file for my application using XCode 3.2.5 (iOS SDK 4.0). But after doing the "Build and Archive" I try to "Save to disk..." the ipa file and nothing happens. The message "Generating IPA file" just dissapears.

I took a look into the console of the Mac and I think I found the issue but no idea how to fix it.  These what I found on the console:

> May 13 15:29:58 Jorge-Martin-Garcias-MacBook-Pro Xcode[246]: Running /usr/bin/xcrun with (\n    "-sdk",\n    iphoneos,\n    PackageApplication,\n    "-v",\n    "/Users/jgarci17/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/16A09235-185F-4F1E-9BFC-A935CAA5699E.apparchive/mWorkf.app",\n    "-o",\n    "/var/folders/pD/pDPQGhivGCCVBsrZpH0VaU+++TI/-Tmp-/D6E45F6F-264A-4714-955A-1EC44E78DFC0-246-0000AFED061085C5/mWorkf.ipa",\n    "--sign",\n    "iPhone Distribution: MyCompany LLC",\n    "--embed",\n    "/Users/jgarci17/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/48D38306-E65F-4D2B-A60A-B94CCD3D518A.mobileprovision"\n)

That seems to be fine, but later ...

> May 13 15:29:58 Jorge-Martin-Garcias-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x16016].com.apple.Xcode[246]: Arguments: embed=/Users/jgarci17/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/48D38306-E65F-4D2B-A60A-B94CCD3D518A.mobileprovision  verbose=1
>
> ==>output_dir=/var/folders/pD/pDPQGhivGCCVBsrZpH0VaU+++TI/-Tmp-/D6E45F6F-264A-4714-955A-1EC44E78DFC0-246-0000AFED061085C5/mWorkf.ipa <===
>
> sign=iPhone Distribution: MyCompany LLC
>
> May 13 15:29:58 Jorge-Martin-Garcias-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x16016].com.apple.Xcode[246]: Output directory: '/var/folders/pD/pDPQGhivGCCVBsrZpH0VaU+++TI/-Tmp-/D6E45F6F-264A-4714-955A-1EC44E78DFC0-246-0000AFED061085C5/mWorkf.ipa

As you see the output directory is including the ipa file name ! ... so later when the zip command wants to run, fails:

> zip error: Could not create output file (/var/folders/pD/pDPQGhivGCCVBsrZpH0VaU+++TI/-Tmp-/D6E45F6F-264A-4714-955A-1EC44E78DFC0-246-0000AFED061085C5/mWorkf.ipa/mWorkf.ipa)

When the correct command should have been:

> zip error: Could not create output file (/var/folders/pD/pDPQGhivGCCVBsrZpH0VaU+++TI/-Tmp-/D6E45F6F-264A-4714-955A-1EC44E78DFC0-246-0000AFED061085C5/mWorkf.ipa)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like the ipa file is being duplicated when it is being generated. The best thing I could suggest is clearing the archive in the organiser and trying to 'share' the application and re-saving the project.

Also, check all your provisioning profiles are installed in the organiser and the distribution certificate is installed in the keychain because this can also disrupt the exporting of an ipa file.